# Symfony JMSTranslationBundle: how to translate variable messages

Tags: symfony

I make a server side check about some things and if something goes wrong, I return an array with some error strings like this:

```
array:7 [▼
  0 => "company.not_valid.not_set.legal_name"
  1 => "company.not_valid.not_set.vat_id"
  2 => "company.not_valid.not_set.address_line1"
  3 => "company.not_valid.not_set.address_locality"
  4 => "company.not_valid.not_set.address_region"
  5 => "company.not_valid.not_set.postal_code"
  6 => "company.not_valid.not_set.address_country"
]
```

So, in the template, I make a for each and print the messages:

```
<ul>
{% for error in errors %}
    <li>{{ error|trans }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But the result, obviously, is this:

```
- company.not_valid.not_set.legal_name
- company.not_valid.not_set.vat_id
- company.not_valid.not_set.address_line1
- company.not_valid.not_set.address_locality
- company.not_valid.not_set.address_region
- company.not_valid.not_set.postal_code
- company.not_valid.not_set.address_country
```

So, how can I manage these translations?

How can I make `app/console translation:extract it --bundle=AppBundle` recognize the placeholder that I put in the array? Where should have I to specify them as existent (as they don't exist in the code until an error happens)?

The only solution I find is to create a file like `_error_messages.html.twig` that, read by the bundle, make it aware of the placeholders.

But is this a correct approach or maybe there is a better one?

Comment: Sorry, what is the problem of manually compile a translation files with them?

Comment: No problem, it's only a bit dirty to have an html.twig file that does nothing more than contain some placeholders... but if this is the way, I'll go with it... in the end... it works!